# Generic type 'Result' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2) - error in swift unit test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I have qritten a test case for JSON Encoding, but I am getting the follwoing error

> Generic type 'Result' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1,
> but expected 2)

I am new to writing tests and any kind of help would be really appreciated. below is the code snippet.

```
  func test_encodeDecodeToFile_happy() {
    let testData = TestData(name: "test", number: 42)
    let url = urlForFile(name: writableFile1)
    let encoded = JsonFileCoder.EncodeToFile(encoded: testData, url: url)
    XCTAssertTrue(encoded)
    let result: Result<TestData> = JsonFileCoder.DecodeFile(url: url)

    switch result {
    case .Success(let decoded):
        XCTAssert(decoded.name == testData.name)
        XCTAssert(decoded.number == testData.number)
    case .Failure(let err):
        XCTFail((err?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
}
```

JsonFileCoder.swift

```
  static func EncodeToFile<T: Encodable>(encoded: T, url: URL) -> Bool {
    if let data = Encode(encoded: encoded) {
        do {
            try data.write(to: url)
            return true
        } catch {
            print("Could not encode \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}

 static func Encode<T: Encodable>(encoded: T) -> Data? {
    if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(encoded) {
        return data
    }
    return nil
}
 static func DecodeFile<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> CurveResult<T> {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe) {
        return Decode(data: data)
    }

    print("Could not decode \(url.absoluteString)")
    return CurveResult.Failure(JsonFileError.couldNotDecode)
}

static func Decode<T: Decodable>(data: Data) -> CurveResult<T> {
    if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) {
        return CurveResult.Success(decoded)
    }

    return CurveResult.Failure(JsonFileError.couldNotDecode)
}
```

Comment: `Result<TestData>`, it should be `Result<TestData, Error>`, or something like that, because `Result<Type1WhenSuccess,Type2WhenError>`, and you haven't that?. And what's the definition of `JsonFileCoder.DecodeFile(url:)`? You show the Encode methods, but we need the decode ones.

Comment: @Larme I have updated the code snippet for decode

Comment: `static func DecodeFile<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> CurveResult<T>` should be `static func DecodeFile<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> CurveResult<T, Error>`, same for `Decode(data:)`. And then, use `Result<TestData, Error>`. And what is `CurveResult`. exactly?

Comment: @Larme Its an enum 
enum CurveResult<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(Error?)
}

Comment: You annotate `result` to `Result<TestData>` which causes the error. And please conform to the naming convention to name enum cases, variables and functions with starting lowercase letter.